# Async calls in express to database *SOMETIMES* fails

Tags: javascript, express, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to build a function that does multiple queries to my cosmos DB in order to build a complete tree hierarchy.

The call is split into multiple functions, the calling method which I call from my web application looks as follows:

```
router.get("/string/:mechanicId", async (req, res) => {
    const querySpec = {
        query: "SELECT c.id, c.name, c.mechanics, c.children FROM c WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.mechanics, {'id': @mechanicId}, true )",
        parameters: [{ name: "@mechanicId", value: req.params.mechanicId }]
    }
    const { resources: databaseDefinition } = await Groups.items.query(querySpec).fetchAll()

    for (let index = 0; index < databaseDefinition.length; index++) {
        await getCompleteTree(databaseDefinition[index])
    }

    databaseDefinition.forEach(obj => {
        splitMechanics(obj)
    })

    res.send(databaseDefinition)
})
```

The first part of my code takes a request parameter named `mechanicId` which it the uses to get the document in my tree that has the mechanicId, the document may look as follows:

```
"id": "07ac90c3-4af9-47ab-be15-116df328e88f",
"mechanics": [
    {
        "id": "mechanicId"
    },
    {
        "id": "mechanicId"
    },
    {
        "id": "mechanicId"
    }
],
"name": "grpName",
"children": [
    {
        "id": "Document_id",
        "name": "childGrpName"
    },
    {
        "id": "Document_id",
        "name": "childGrpName"
    }
],
```

All my child documents have the same structure - Please notice, that the document has an array of child objects, which is used to build the rest of the tree.

Next, once I have the top document, I want to query all child groups and patch them into the `children` array. The following is done in the function named `getCompleteTree()` - I loop over the fetched documents, because a mechanic may have multiple trees which he belongs to.

The function `getCompleteTree()` looks as follows:

```
async function getCompleteTree(groupObj) {
    for (let index = 0; index < groupObj.children.length; index++) {
        await Groups.items.query(`SELECT c.id, c.parent, c.name, c.mechanics, c.children FROM c WHERE c.id = "${groupObj.children[index].id}"`).fetchAll().then((obj) => obj.resources).then((obj) => {
            groupObj.children[index] = obj[0]
        })
    }
    for (let index = 0; index < groupObj.children.length; index++) {
        await getCompleteTree(groupObj.children[index])
    }
}
```

In `getCompleteTree()` I'm doing the following steps:

- Loop over each children in parent object `groupObj`
- Fetch every child document for the parent
- set each children in parent equal to the fetched children
- If the children of the parent has children, I start a recursive loop.

Once `getCompleteTree()` is done, I'm taking the main object and performing work on it, which is done in the following function:

```
function splitMechanics(groupObj) {
    for (index = 0; index < groupObj.mechanics.length; index++) { //<------- THIS FAILS, mechanics undefined
        //Do some synchronous work here
    }
    groupObj.children && groupObj.children.forEach(obj => {
        splitMechanics(obj)
    })
}
```

I've left some code out, as it's unnecessary.

Most of the time, the above-mentioned flow works perfectly - No problems what-so-ever. But sometimes, my function `splitMechanics()` which is called after the entire hierarchy is build, fails. Specifically it fails because some lower-level child-documents does not contain the `groupObj.mechanics` property - Therefore I get an undefined exception.
All child documents contains the `mechanics` property - For some reason the child object has just not been called and appended in my `getCompleteTree()` function (I believe)

I suspect that I get the error, because I have a lot of asynchronous logic - Especially when I'm building the tree. However, I do have a hard time figuring out what cause my code to be "unstable".

All async calls are awaited - Which to me should solve eventual issues, with resolving promises.

Comment: 1) Can you add the `queryTree()` function definition ? And, 2 about this : `await Groups.items.query(query).fetchAll().then((obj) => obj.resources).then((obj) => { groupObj.children[index] = obj[0] })`" If I where you, I would investigate what happen to your code if, for some reason, the obj.resources promise resolve to an empty array. Then, your obj[0] is null. What it would say is that, maybe, your DB query return no result. And so, you may get a clue on the "why" you get null. Is that specific to an ID (always the same or not), for example.

Comment: I just edited my question - I made a typo in terms of `queryTree()` :-( 

It is always the same item that fails actually - Which is strange, because it looks similar to all other documents.

Comment: Ok. You should try to simplify your problem. Request a doc with an ID that you are sure is OK. Print it fully. Then get your failing ID and compare its structure. Search for a typo or a non visible character in the ID for exemple.

Comment: But such would cause it to fail all the time - This is only periodically.

Comment: Exact. You may want to print an exact stack trace of what happen. It may be painfull to read, but try to log all your queries result. You will maybe detect an order in which it happen. But since it specific to an ID, it can be caching problem too... It's not really undeterministic as it can be with a synchronisation problem, since it happen to only this ID.

Comment: Well - I already concluded, that the particular for-loop runs over every child twice. Which makes absolutely no sense. Could indicate that my async call is bad.

Comment: What if you don't use two loops in your get Complete Tree and just call your `await getCompleteTree(groupObj.children[index])` right after your first await?